# Taking the port from Boost Asio socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, port

I'm triying to take the client port of a Boost Asio Server.

I put here some code with the relevant information:

Client:

```
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::asio::connect(client_socket, resolver.resolve({"127.0.0.1", "50013" }));
```

Server:

```
    const int SERVER_PORT = 50013;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server(io_service, SERVER_PORT);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), SERVER_PORT);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* socket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(*socket);
```

I have the socket declared with pointer, because in my code is with functions.
Then in the server I have something like this, for doing my log (I paste only the part of ports).

```
unsigned short port = socket->remote_endpoint().port();
...
fprintf(pFile, "%hu\n",port);
...
```

My problem is, that in my out file (of the fprintf), the port that it appear isn't 50013.
In concret it appear: *61964*

And I don't understand why.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `fprintf` in you code is called on the server side. So `remote_endpoint().port()` for it will be equal to the port that your client is using to connect to server, and this port will be chosen randomly by OS from dynamic ports range. It will not be equal to 50013, because your client/server application communicate via localhost, so port 50013 is already used by server. If you realy want it to print 50013 you should use `local_endpoint()`.

Comment: oh! Thankyou very much! You are the boss :P
It works perfect! I didn't know this randomly asing by OS for client..
Thank you very much for resolve it and for this free knowledge!